# proving that a function doesn't satisfy lipschitz condition

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Prove that f(x)=$\sqrt{1-x^2}$ does not satisfy a Lipchitz condition on [-1,1].
My solution: 
Suppose on the contrary that f does satisfy a lipschitz condition on [-1,1], then
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M|x-y| $$ In particular, let y=1.
$$|\sqrt{1-x^2}|\leq M|x-1|$$
$$ \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x}\leq M$$
However
$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x}= \infty $$
It's just a sketch, but is this a valid proof?

Comment: That breaks Lipschitz, pure and simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it more explicit with no need to talk about limits. If you consider $x=1-1/n$, then
$$
M>\frac{\sqrt{1-(1-1/n)^2}}{1/n}=n\,\sqrt{2/n-1/n^2}=\sqrt n\,\sqrt{2-1/n}>\sqrt n.
$$
As this can be done for every $n>0$, the desired number $M$ cannot exist.